# Como faço o Python clicar em um botão no google?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, google, selenium-webdriver, agendamento

estou fazendo um bot que entra no google meet em horas agendadas, consegui a parte de abrir as reuniões nas horas desejadas, mas esbarei no problema de que o programa precisa clicar no botão de "entrar" é eu não sei como faço isso, minha tentativa mais recente foi com o Selenium mas mas quando eu executo aparece esse erro no console: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome' has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

se puder sugerir uma forma de fazer um click que seja mais simples do que o selenium também é valido

```
import os
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

hora = 3600
driver = webdriver.chrome

def segunda():
    if now.hour == 16:
        os.startfile('link da reunião')
        sleep(10)
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/span").click()
        sleep(hora)

while True:
    
    now = datetime.now()
    data = date(now.year, now.month, now.day)

#segunda
    if data.isoweekday() == 1:
        segunda()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, você está indo bem. Para clicar em um botão você deve localiza-lo usando por: xpath, id, class ou tag e depois usar o método `.click()`.

1 - geckodriver

```
my_button = drive.find_element_by_id("my-button")
my_button.click()
```

2 - editada

**Erro no seu código**

```
# Preste mais atencao

drive = webdrive.chrome  # errado
drive = webdrive.Chrome()  # certo
```

Outra forma de buscar um elemento. Apesar de não ser o foco da pergunta...

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# resto do seu código

my_button = drive.find_element(By.ID, "my-button")
my_button.click()
```

**Você pode usar a forma que achar melhor para  encontrar o elemento como `id`, `xpath`, `tag name`, `class` e `css selector`.**

[**Leia a documentaçaõ com mais detalhes!!!**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms)

Obrigado pelos downvotes :)

Comment: o método de find element da o seguinte erro: module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome' has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'

Comment: Sua pergunta era "como clicar em um botão" e foi o que procurei responder. Adicionei mais detalhes...